# Mahento 2 : How to associate more simple products with an existing configurable product programatically?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to update a configurable product programmatically but when i am running the script i am getting "Option values are not specified." exception. I am not sure whats wrong i am doing. Here is code that i am using

```
    $superAttribute = [151,152];
    configurableProductId =10;
    $sku = "B510";

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // instance of object manager
    $productFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $configurableProduct = $productFactory->load($configurableProductId);

    $simpleProductIds = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

    $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable')->setUsedProductAttributeIds($superAttribute, $configurableProduct);
    $configurableProduct->setAssociatedProductIds($simpleProductIds);// Setting Associated Products
    $configurableProduct->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
    $configurableProduct->save();

    $output->writeln($sku.' configurable product updated');
```

Note: We need to update already created configurable products not to create new configurable product. Also, please ignore the use of object manager. I am aware that the use of the object manager is not recommended.

Comment: Please have a look on : https://webkul.com/blog/assign-associated-products/

Comment: @pawan: I have checked webkul blog. That doesn't work. Does it work for you?

Comment: I have not tried that, thought it should be work.